# Compare Native Script and Ionic and Need a Native Script Tutorial - Hybrid Apps

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui

Which Technology is better for hybrid app development Ionic or Native Script ?
or else suggest a technology but i know Angular 6 ?
i need a Native Script Tutorial much better if its a video Tutorial torrent link.

What is Developer ratings for different Hybrid App Development technologies.
I am new in technology.

Hybrid App development Guidance

Answer (score 3):

NativeScript is not exactly a hybrid platform and you can't compare it with Ionic or Cordova where they use a WebView to render your HTML web page.

With NativeScript your UI is completely native. If you use a Button it will be the [android.widget.Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button) on Android / [UIButtom](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton?language=objc) on iOS. It's like you are building a pure native app with your web skills.

You may compare NativeScript with Xamarin as they are kind of similar in architecture. If you have a team well versed in C# you might probably choose Xamarin and wise to choose NativeScript when your tech-stack is JavaScript.

Comment: my tech stack is angular 6 so which will be the best ionic 4 or native script for developing hybrid applications ?

Comment: That depends on what your goals are, if you like a smooth native UI and easy access to native api etc., then NativeScript will be your choice. Watch this [video presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rb8smP_xTTY) which might give you a better understanding of native over hybrid apps.

Comment: ill go for ionic 4 thnkiu manoj

Comment: Yeah it depends what your goal is. The biggest difference between IONIC and NS is layouting. NS doesn't use HTML (so say goodbye to divs). If you're more on the code logic side, then it doesn't really matter. They are both powered by Angular (with some minor modifications).